# Detrended canonical correspondence analysis in R

Tags: r, bioinformatics, correspondence-analysis

Is it possible to perform a Detrended Canonical Correspondence Analysis in R? Im looking to analyse ecological (pollen) data to investigate beta diversity through time. As far as I can tell I have to perform these analyses in CANOCO, which I want to avoid.

Comment: See [vegan](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vegan/index.html).

Comment: @chl what if I'm not vegan? ;)

Answer (score 0):

[decorana](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/vegan/versions/2.4-2/topics/decorana) function from the [vegan](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vegan/index.html) package does it.